# JAXB generates a camelcase root entity name despite specified differently

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb

I'm using following class to map entity into XML

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@XmlRootElement(name = "orders")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Order { ....
```

As you see root element name is specified but it's ignored.
What I get is

```
<Order><losOrderId>42</losOrderId>
```

But I need to have

```
<orders>
```

as a root element.

Comment: Please show a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The issue what that "com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat" was configured in the project, this thing ignore JAXB annotations by marshalling.

One need to use @JacksonXmlRootElement /  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "creds") in this case.